# ASP.NET: Controls are null when I try to change a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

1. Created a user control.
2. Within user control, I have a simple control, like a Literal, in the markup.
3. In the user control's Page_Load, I attempt to change a property, like Text, on control created in the markup.
4. Control is null.

What in the world am I missing?










(Begin rant: I am doing all these fancy things with login systems and dynamically adding/modifying controls on the fly with AJAX, etc, but I can't change an f'n static control's property!  I can't even Google such a simple problem without finding something else!  In the past, I had to dynamically generate the whole bloody page to avoid this idiotically simple problem.  End rant.)

Comment: can you give some code samples? The markup and the Page_load() method would be helpful.

Comment: Does the UserControl load at all? It loads fine, but the text isn't changed? Or, the UserControl isn't loading or comes up empty/blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way after analyzing the order a page is executed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   literalGameName.Text = myGame.Name;
}
```

Init happens after controls have been made, but not after the page is done loading control-stuff.

Comment: Oh, and can someone vote this as the correct answer?  

(It says I have to wait two days to vote my own answer as the right answer!  I guess we don't trust people to solve their own problems, eh?  :-P)

Answer (score 0):

Page.LoadControl() has two overloads, one accepts a Virtual Path, the other accepts a Type.
Sometimes, when using the Type version overload, you get this kind of behaviour.

When possible, try to use the Virtual Path version of LoadControl.

Edit: as an FYI, this is because the actual Type of a User Control is not what you would expect it to be. ASP.NET kind of 'wraps' the Type of the User Control.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but wanted to chime in on how I fixed a similar issue I was having. I have a usercontrol with an asp:Panel on it that I was trying to set the visibility off during the Page_Load, but the control was coming up null. I then noticed that my Page_Load definition looked like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _myControl.visible = true;
}
```

When in fact, I needed the definition to look like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    _myControl.visible = true;
}
```

Doing the override fixed the issue.